# Is it possible to populate a single document that i already have?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose for a database which consists of a user-model (=USER). And the user has friends which are being kept like this:

```
friends:  [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'}]
```

And the user can view a list of all his friends and visit their profile by clicking on the username (in the list) but at that moment the 'friends' array of the friend is not yet populated. Is there a way to populate this array when the username gets clicked without havin to use USER.findOne? So i mean if friend is the variable which holds the friend object, do something like friend.populate.

-I also use passport.js so the logged in user can always be found in req.user, i would also like to populate this one without having to find him in the db.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question as [`doc.populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate) will do exactly what you want. Regardless though, even `populate` calls to the DB to get the user document as that is the only place it is stored.